# Create Parent/Child ID's for Hierarchical Data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, hierarchical-data, tidy

I have some hierarchical data that I am trying to get into a more relational style table. I want to mutate a column to my dataframe that tells me the parent to each row. Here, Lights is a child to Electrical, and Wiring and Bulbs are both children to Lights, and so on. Is there a way I can say "if Level = 2, find the nearest Level 1 above it in the dataframe, and assign that as its parent?" Another example would be: if the row is a Level 3 item (Wiring), its parent would be the nearest Level 2 above it in the dataframe (Lights).

I would need the nearest Level above it since the data is stored hierarchically.

```
Level   Group    Name     Price
1        01    Electrical  200
2        01    Lights      82
3        01    Wiring      60
3        01    Bulbs       22
2        01    Vent        118
3        01    Detector    60
3        01    Cable       20
3        01    Plastic     25
3        01    Brackets    13

1        02    Interior    500
2        02    Doors       300
3        02    Knobs       40
2        02    Trim        200
3        02    Shelves     150
4        02    Brackets    50
```

Desired Output would be something like:

```
Level   Group    Name     Price  ID Parent
1        01    Electrical  200   1   None 
2        01    Lights      82    2    1
3        01    Wiring      60    3    2
3        01    Bulbs       22    4    2
2        01    Vent        118   5    1
3        01    Detector    60    6    5
3        01    Cable       20    7    5
3        01    Plastic     25    8    5
3        01    Brackets    13    9    5

1        02    Interior    500   10  None
2        02    Doors       300   11   10
3        02    Knobs       40    12   11
2        02    Trim        200   13   10
3        02    Shelves     150   14   13
4        02    Brackets    50    15   14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this but I think there should be other better/efficient solution to this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Parent = map2_dbl(Level, ID, ~{
    tmp <- ID[Level == .x - 1]
    val <- tmp - .y
    if(any(val < 0)) max(tmp[val < 0]) else NA
    })) %>%
  ungroup

#   Level Group Name       Price    ID Parent
#   <int> <int> <chr>      <int> <int>  <dbl>
# 1     1     1 Electrical   200     1     NA
# 2     2     1 Lights        82     2      1
# 3     3     1 Wiring        60     3      2
# 4     3     1 Bulbs         22     4      2
# 5     2     1 Vent         118     5      1
# 6     3     1 Detector      60     6      5
# 7     3     1 Cable         20     7      5
# 8     3     1 Plastic       25     8      5
# 9     3     1 Brackets      13     9      5
#10     1     2 Interior     500    10     NA
#11     2     2 Doors        300    11     10
#12     3     2 Knobs         40    12     11
#13     2     2 Trim         200    13     10
#14     3     2 Shelves      150    14     13
#15     4     2 Brackets      50    15     14
```

We create and `ID` column which is row number in the dataframe and for each `Level` in the group we find out the nearest `ID` value which is one level above the current level.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. And if we instead wanted any NA's in the Parent column to refer to itself (aka ID 1 would have Parent listed as 1, and ID 10 would have Parent 10), how would we achieve that? @Ronak Shah

Comment: Instead of `NA` return `.y` i.e `if(any(val < 0)) max(tmp[val < 0]) else .y`